# -Contains operator not working powershell

Tags: powershell

All I'm trying to do is to see if the user input $month is in the array $months. But it's not liking something. Help?

```
Write-host "The script is to collect from the user High Tempature and Low Tempature for a day in degrees F."
$months = @("January", "February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
$finished = $false
while ($finished -eq $false){
    $month = read-host "Enter the month";
    if ($months -Contains $month)
    {
        write-host "Invalid entry"
        $finished = $false
    }
    else
    {
        $finished = $true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You test logic is just not the good one, just reverse youy test or reverse your actions:

```
Write-host "The script is to collect from the user High Tempature and Low Tempature for a day in degrees F."
$months = @("January", "February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
$finished = $false
while ($finished -eq $false){
    $month = read-host "Enter the month";
    if ($months -Contains $month)
    {
        $finished = $true
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "Invalid entry"
        $finished = $false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `-Contains` you should just run a RegEx match using the `-Match` operator. Or, as you are currently testing for a negative result, use `-notmatch` instead. You can use your existing code, just modify it a little by joining your months with a pipe character. Like:

```
Write-host "The script is to collect from the user High Tempature and Low Tempature for a day in degrees F."
$months = @("January", "February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")
$finished = $false
while ($finished -eq $false){
    $month = read-host "Enter the month";
    if ($month -notmatch ($months -join "|"))
    {
        write-host "Invalid entry"


     $finished = $false
    }
    else
    {
        $finished = $true
    }
}
```

Better yet, let's get rid of the If/Else and shorten this. Move the Join to where we define `$Months`, and then ask for a month and if it isn't a match ask for it again until it is with a While.

```
$months = @("January", "February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December") -join '|'
$month = read-host "Enter the month"
While($month -notmatch $months){
    "Invalid Entry"
    $month = read-host "Enter the month"
}
```

Comment: @JPBlanc It works if he does it right, yes, but isn't he going to run into case sensitivity issues? Or is -contains case insensitive?

Comment: `CContains` is case sensitive, not `Contains`.

Comment: I don't think switching a contains to a regex is a good trade.

Comment: @MikeShepard it's been shown that comparing a RegEx match such as this has better performance than using the -contains operator, so this is a fairly common practice I think.